# What is the correct way to declare an HTML5 Doctype.

Tags: html, doctype

What is the correct way to use  start tag when creating with HTML5

IE: HTML 4 Strict is like this

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html> <!-- all thats needed -->

Answer (score 65):

The standard has been simplified because the previous doctypes were too cryptic.  The new doctype is simply `<!DOCTYPE html>` .  You may wonder why it is not `<!DOCTYPE html5>` but it is simply because it is just an update to the standard of HTML and not a new version of anything.  As you can see below, all elements can now have a language attribute.

> The `<html>` element is the root element of a document. Every document
>   must begin with this element, and it must contain both the `<head>` and
>   `<body>` elements.
>
> It is considered good practice to specify the primary language of the
>   document on this element using the lang attribute.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
        <p>
            Jamie was here.
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

More info: https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/#doctype-declaration

Answer (score 20):

you just use

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
</html>
```

Comment: Just nitpicking :) `<html lang="es">` or `<html lang="fr_qc">` will add a default language to both title and body elements (i.e. the whole page)

Answer (score 9):

First of all, **html5 doctype is not case sensitive**.

Either one of these three will work:

1) `<!DOCTYPE html>`

2) `<!DOCTYPE HTML>`

3) `<!doctype html>`

You can check the validity [here.](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input)

Answer (score 6):

It's as simple as

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
```

Answer (score 4):

According to the WWW Consortium, the organization responsible setting current web standards, no one has answered this correctly.
The current standard for language declaration is

> **Always** use a language attribute on the html tag to declare the default
>   language of the text in the page. When the page contains content in another
>   language, add a language attribute to an element surrounding that content.
>   Use the lang attribute for pages served as HTML, and the xml:lang attribute 
>   for pages served as XML. For XHTML 1.x and HTML5 polyglot documents, use both 
>   together.
>   [W3C HTML Language Tag Page](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-language-declarations)

Here is the answer regarding DOCTYPE declaration

> Use the following markup as a template to create a new HTML document using a 
>   proper Doctype declaration. See the list below if you wish to use another DTD.
>   [W3C DOCTYPE Standards](https://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>An HTML standard template</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8"  />
</head>

<body>
     <p>… Your HTML content here …</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The example doesn't have "a language attribute declaring the default language" like your first point says?

Answer (score 3):

You use...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

followed by your HTML tag etc..

Answer (score 2):

You only need this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
...
```

There are several points here. This is supported by all browsers, even old ones like IE6/IE7. All browsers actually nee "html" part from doctype declaration to jump into standards mode.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- simplified doctype works for all previous versions of HTML as well -->
<!doctype html>
```

**Learning Resource:**

- http://diveintohtml5.info/
- http://www.html5doctor.com

Answer (score 0):

The start tag `<html>` is optional in HTML5, as in HTML 4.01. If used, it must be the first tag. It has different optional attributes: the global attributes of HTML5, and the special `manifest` attribute. The most common useful attribute in the `<html>` tag is the `lang` attribute.

(The doctype declaration is something quite different, and not a tag at all.)

Comment: @AlexW - Try section 8.1.2.4 on the same page that you link to.

Comment: "A DOCTYPE is a required preamble." in HTML 5.3 according to http://w3c.github.io/html/syntax.html#the-doctype

Answer (score 0):

The clearest most definitive answer of what the standard says seems to be for HTML 5.3 at:

http://w3c.github.io/html/syntax.html#the-doctype

Note especially the list-items 1 and 3 which specify that the doctype-statement is case-insensitive. Also note the number of spaces inside the statement can vary.

And note the clause "A DOCTYPE is a required preamble."