# Using Javascript to change website language

Tags: javascript, html, translation

I'm working on a GUI website that can use several languages. The original HTML-files I got to work with were totally static. So if translation was needed I had to parse through alle files, note where some words or terms were, collect them all hand them to the translation department and enter those translations in the new language files.

Since those files were totally static it meant having to translate whole sections several times. Not very effictient.

So now I am working on some kind of dictionary in Javascript, to just exchange the terms in those websites. Mostly it works this way:

```
var dicEnglish = {
term 1: "This is the English text"
Ref: "Another English text"
}
var dicFrench = {
term 1: "This is the French text"
Ref: "Another French text"   
}
```

Which contains all the possible content that needs to be changed. Every candidate in the HTML-code gets a `class="dicRef" id="l_dicTag_#"`as identifier, which I slice down to the dictionary tag and exchange with the following code:

```
var imgSrc = "en";
var ActiveDic;
var langSel;
if(window.name){
    langSel=window.name;
    }
else{langSel="English";
}

function LangChange(){
langClass = document.getElementsByClassName("dicRef");
var i = langClass.length;
var Start, Stop, idSrc, idDic;
var navText;

switch(langSel){
    case "French":
        langSel="French";
        imgSrc = "en";
        navText="Anglais";
        break;
    case "English":
    case "Anglais":
    default:
        langSel="English";
        imgSrc = "fr";
        navText="French";
        break;
    }
ActiveDic="dic"+langSel;
window.name=langSel;

while(i--){
    idSrc = langClass[i].id;
    Start=idSrc.indexOf("_")+1;
    Stop=idSrc.lastIndexOf("_");
    idDic=idSrc.slice(Start,Stop);
    if(window[ActiveDic][idDic]){
        document.getElementById(idSrc).innerHTML=window[ActiveDic][idDic];}
    else{
        document.getElementById(idSrc).innerHTML="N/A";
    }
}
if(document.getElementById("imgSel")){
    document.getElementById("imgSel").src="../../img/"+imgSrc+".gif";
}
if (document.getElementById("l_SelLang1_1")){
    document.getElementById("l_SelLang1_1").innerHTML=navText;
}
}
```

The problem lies in the uniqueness of the id-tag. Since some terms can occur more than once and some are generated the counter is needed. I'd prefer to ommit the counter, but can't find any other identifier to sort out all target terms and change their content.

Since I want to be safe for the future I'd prefer a solution that makes it possible to handle a possible third language. Working with the inner HTML would need to tag the same term several times, once for each language.

So is there any way to target all terms to be exchanged more efficently and easily, or a better way to do it? I can only work with client-side solutions, so no PHP and so on.

Comment: I have to admit, since I'm new to deeper HTML and completely to Javascript I didn't know that, because W3C Schools starts with HTML 4. ;) What about backward compatibility. Specs say it has to work with IE 7 or Firefox 3.5 (and later of course). I find contradicting information on HTML 5 and old browsers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use data attributes: the fact that "HTML5 attributes are not supported in IE6 and IE7" means that you don't get the `getAttribute()` method or the `dataset` property for retrieving/accessing them. But you can still retrieve them as explained in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2412947/do-html5-custom-data-attributes-work-in-ie-6).

```
<div id="geoff" data-geoff="geoff">
```

```
var geoff = document.getElementById("geoff");
alert(geoff.getAttribute("data-geoff"));
```

Even better, you can use jQuery [.data()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/) to support previous versions of IE.

Something along these lines should work:

```
<div data-translate="translation_key"></div>
```

```
$("[data-translate]").each(function(){
    var key = $(this).data('translate');
    $(this).html(dictionary[key][current_lang] || "N/A");
});
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/x93oLad8/4/

Comment: Please note that jQuery's `data` only works with json encoded values, so you'd need to quote and escape the contents of the data attribute in this case (which isn't too convenient when working with just scalar values).

Comment: Well thanks for pointing that out, but I think it won't be a limitation in this case since translation keys should be plain alphanumeric strings, possibly with underscore as separator, and shouldn't need any special escaping.

Comment: Sorry, I checked [the docs](https://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5) on this and I am in error. String values are loaded as-is, you don't need to encode them in JSON.

Comment: This is a good solution, but note that in iPad and in another cases it doesn't works. You need to call dataSet() and extract values from this like this mode: `var key = $(this).dataSet(); console.log(key.translate);`. With this it works in all browsers and devices.

Comment: Why wouldn't this work on iPad? Can you provide a specific reason?

Comment: Just a note: the OP hasn't specified they're using jQuery.

Comment: Thanks, I noticed. The OP question is how to workaround the problem he's having with id uniqueness and my answer is to use data attributes. Then I give an implementation of a translation system with two lines of jQuery code, the OP is free to implement one in vanilla Javascript or maybe go with your template solution if he likes better yours ;)

Comment: Those methods work, but now the HTML validator is complaining about the use of the  proprietary attribute "data" (Using HTML tidy). I thought data would be conform and standard with HTML5.  Will this HTML code still be clean?

Comment: Data attributes are standard HTML5, maybe you are not declaring the right doctype for HTML5? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10963135/what-is-the-correct-way-to-declare-an-html5-doctype

Answer (score 61):

No offense to the other answerers but storing the text in JavaScript or in data attributes is not good for search engines or disabled site visitors and offers no benefits while added unnecessarily complicated code. The best and most simple solution in my opinion is to make use of HTML lang attribute and use JavaScript to show and hide the desired language. This solution also gracefully degrades so if a site visitor has their JavaScript disabled it will still display the content. Here is my solution:

**HTML**

```
<button id="switch-lang">Switch Language</button>

<h1><span lang="en">Hello</span> <span lang="es">Hola</span></h1>

<p lang="en">I really enjoy coding.</p>

<p lang="es">Me gusta mucho la codificación.</p>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('[lang="es"]').hide();

$('#switch-lang').click(function() {
  $('[lang="es"]').toggle();
  $('[lang="en"]').toggle();
});
```

Then I would recommend adding HTML5 Geolocation to determine which language to show initially based on the users location in the world. I would also use Fontawesome language icon to show users they can switch languages in a way that is understandable by anyone: http://fontawesome.io/icon/language/

Here is the working code example at CodePen: https://codepen.io/codepajamas/pen/ZejaQz?editors=1010

Here is an additional example on JSFiddle using a select menu to change between 3
(or more) languages: https://jsfiddle.net/726kgom1/1/

**Updated Full Example with Geolocation and Cookies**

I kept working on this and created an updated example switching between two languages Chinese and English (if you need more than two languages you would have to hide all languages and show only the one selected instead of using toggle the way I am). This code also detects if an existing cookie is already set for the language using jQuery Cookie. It also checks their geolocation if their browser supports it automatically setting the language to Chinese if they are in either Taiwan or China and defaults to English in all other countries. The code below is commented so you can see what each step is doing and hopefully be able to modify it to suit your needs. Here it is:

**HTML**

```
<button id="switch-lang">Switch Language Icon Here</button>

<h1><span lang="en">Hello</span> <span lang="zh">你好</span></h1>

<p lang="en">I really enjoy coding.</p>

<p lang="zh">我真的很喜歡編碼。</p>
```

**jQuery**
Note: this requires linking to not only [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) but also [jQuery Cookie](https://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/)

```
$(function () {
  ///// Language Switching (2 languages: English and Chinese). /////

  // Initially disable language switching button.
  $('#switch-lang').css({'pointer-events':'none',
   'cursor':'default'}).attr('disabled','disabled');

  function langButtonListen() {
    $('#switch-lang').click(function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $('[lang="zh"]').toggle();
      $('[lang="en"]').toggle();
      // Switch cookie stored language.
      if ($.cookie('lang') === 'en') {
        $.cookie('lang', 'zh', { expires: 7 });
      } else {
        $.cookie('lang', 'en', { expires: 7 });
      }
    });
    // Enable lang switching button.
    $('#switch-lang').css({'pointer-events':'auto',
     'cursor':'pointer'}).removeAttr('disabled');
  }

  // Check if language cookie already exists.
  if ($.cookie('lang')) {
    var lang = $.cookie('lang');
    if (lang === 'en') {
      $('[lang="zh"]').hide();
      langButtonListen();
    } else {
      $('[lang="en"]').hide();
      langButtonListen();
    }
  } else {
    // no cookie set, so detect language based on location.
    if ("geolocation" in navigator) {
      // geolocation is available
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
        // accepted geolocation so figure out which country
        var lat = position.coords.latitude,
            lng = position.coords.longitude;
        $.getJSON('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng='+lat+','+lng+'&sensor=true', null, function (response) {
          var country = response.results[response.results.length-1].formatted_address;
          if (country ===  'Taiwan' || country === 'China') {
            $('[lang="en"]').hide();
            $.cookie('lang', 'zh', { expires: 7 });
            langButtonListen();
          } else {
            $('[lang="zh"]').hide();
            $.cookie('lang', 'en', { expires: 7 });
            langButtonListen();
          }
        }).fail(function (err) {
          console.log('error: '+err);
          $('[lang="zh"]').hide();
          $.cookie('lang', 'en', { expires: 7 });
          langButtonListen();
        });
      },
      function (error) {
        if (error.code == error.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
          // denied geolocation
          $('[lang="zh"]').hide();
          $.cookie('lang', 'en', { expires: 7 });
          langButtonListen();
        } else {
          console.log('Unknown error. Defaulting to English!');
          $('[lang="zh"]').hide();
          $.cookie('lang', 'en', { expires: 7 });
          langButtonListen();
        }
      });
    } else {
      // geolocation IS NOT available
      $('[lang="zh"]').hide();
      $.cookie('lang', 'en', { expires: 7 });
      langButtonListen());
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: This is a very nice solution!

Comment: Most elegant solution I've seen :)

Comment: Very nice. In my case disabled visitors and search engines wont be an issue, since it an embedded website for customers, so needed language combinations will change.

Comment: Yes, this is a nice solution, but what if your Website has to support more than 3 languages? then you are stuck with stacks of nearly identical html tags.
So this works better with small sites, where the effort isn't worth it to build a language translation system.
And you can leave text in the tag, to allow visitors with disabled Javascript to read the site anyways, and it would not even be as messy as having three identical tags.

Comment: Nice solution, just one comment from my part: never, never, never ever use IP geolocation to select the display language. Imagine someone who’s traveling and is getting the site displayed in Thai – this is probably not what your users would want. There is a language preference which pretty much every browser supports, sent as part of the HTTP request and also available as a Javascript constant `navigator.language`. By default this is the UI language of the browser, but the user can change it.

Comment: Added a three or more language example with drop down menu at JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/726kgom1/1/

Answer (score 4):

One of the ways around this might be to use some sort of client-side templating system for your interface. That way you don't need to unnecessarily load your HTML with a bunch of data attributes detailing the language requirements, but just describe it once in the JavaScript and use a couple of functions to assist with the translation. I've coded up quick  example below to show you what I mean.

Here's the dictionary object. It contains *all* the translations by country code. This means you don't need *separate* dictionaries for each country. This is important because it means we can use this single object structure very easily in out translation function as you'll see in a moment. It also means you can add as many languages and translations as you like.

```
var dict = {
    en: {
        'Hallo': 'Hallo',
        'Goodbye': 'Goodbye',
        'castle': 'castle'
    },
    fr: {
        'Hallo': 'Bonjour',
        'Goodbye': 'Au revoir',
        'castle': 'chateau'
    },
    de: {
        'Hallo': 'Hallo',
        'Goodbye': 'Auf Wiedersehen',
        'castle': 'schloss'
    }
}
```

This is our country code and it relates directly to the country code key in our dictionary object:

```
var lang = 'fr';
```

The first of our two functions. This takes a template and a language and performs the translation, returning whatever's left (usually some sort of HTML as in our example).

```
function applyTemplate(tmpl, lang) {

    // find all words within {{word}} a double set of curly braces
    // (this format is similar to the handlebars templating engine)
    var regex = /\{\{([a-zA-Z])\w+\}\}/g

    // for each found word perform the translation and
    // remove the curly braces
    return tmpl.replace(regex, function (word) {
        return translate(dict, lang, word.replace(/[\{\}]/g, ''));
    });
}
```

The translate function takes the dictionary, the language, and a word and returns the translated word. Note that this is much easier with one object containing all the country translations.

```
function translate(dict, lang, word) {
    return dict[lang][word];
}
```

Some HTML. Here is our template (display: none) and the output element. Note the words in the curly braces are the ones to be translated.

```
<div class="template"><div>{{Goodbye}}, {{castle}}</div></div>
<div id="translation"></div>
```

Finally, putting it all together:

```
//  grab the template
var tmpl = document.querySelector('.template').textContent;
var translation = document.querySelector('#translation');

// grab our translated html and add it to the output element
var html = applyTemplate(tmpl, lang);
translation.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', html);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mjf2ovzw/9/)

Now, obviously you don't have to use this method (there are dozens of JS templating engines out there), but templating is *particularly* useful for sites that need to use multiple languages. Many do this on the back end but, as you can see, it can be easily done client-side too.

Hope this was useful and given you a couple of different ideas on how you might approach your solution.

Comment: The above solution works pretty nicely. I'd recommend one slight modification though.
First, close the  id="translation" <div> tag
Second, use the innerHtml property instead of replaceAdjacentHTML(). That way you can run multiple translations without duplicating the actual text.

Comment: Definitely use this, server-side resources are expandable and customisable and not dependent on JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
```

// Load the Google Transliteration API
      google.load("elements", "1", {
            packages: "transliteration"
          });

```
  var transliterationControl;
  function onLoad() {
    var options = {
        sourceLanguage: 'en',
        destinationLanguage: ['hi','or','bn','ta','te'],
        transliterationEnabled: true,
        shortcutKey: 'ctrl+g'
    };
    // Create an instance on TransliterationControl with the required
    // options.
    transliterationControl =
      new google.elements.transliteration.TransliterationControl(options);

    // Enable transliteration in the textfields with the given ids.
    var ids = [ "transl1", "transl2" ];
    transliterationControl.makeTransliteratable(ids);

    // Add the STATE_CHANGED event handler to correcly maintain the state
    // of the checkbox.
    transliterationControl.addEventListener(
        google.elements.transliteration.TransliterationControl.EventType.STATE_CHANGED,
        transliterateStateChangeHandler);

    // Add the SERVER_UNREACHABLE event handler to display an error message
    // if unable to reach the server.
    transliterationControl.addEventListener(
        google.elements.transliteration.TransliterationControl.EventType.SERVER_UNREACHABLE,
        serverUnreachableHandler);

    // Add the SERVER_REACHABLE event handler to remove the error message
    // once the server becomes reachable.
    transliterationControl.addEventListener(
        google.elements.transliteration.TransliterationControl.EventType.SERVER_REACHABLE,
        serverReachableHandler);

    // Set the checkbox to the correct state.
    document.getElementById('checkboxId').checked =
      transliterationControl.isTransliterationEnabled();

    // Populate the language dropdown
    var destinationLanguage =
      transliterationControl.getLanguagePair().destinationLanguage;
    var languageSelect = document.getElementById('languageDropDown');
    var supportedDestinationLanguages =
      google.elements.transliteration.getDestinationLanguages(
        google.elements.transliteration.LanguageCode.ENGLISH);
    for (var lang in supportedDestinationLanguages) {
      var opt = document.createElement('option');
      opt.text = lang;
if (lang=="TAMIL" || lang=="TELUGU" || lang=="HINDI" || lang=="ORIYA" || lang=="BENGALI"){
      opt.value = supportedDestinationLanguages[lang];
      if (destinationLanguage == opt.value) {
        opt.selected = true;
      }
      try {
        languageSelect.add(opt, null);
      } catch (ex) {
        languageSelect.add(opt);
      }
}//End of if
    }
  }

  // Handler for STATE_CHANGED event which makes sure checkbox status
  // reflects the transliteration enabled or disabled status.
  function transliterateStateChangeHandler(e) {
    document.getElementById('checkboxId').checked = e.transliterationEnabled;
  }

  // Handler for checkbox's click event.  Calls toggleTransliteration to toggle
  // the transliteration state.
  function checkboxClickHandler() {
    transliterationControl.toggleTransliteration();
  }

  // Handler for dropdown option change event.  Calls setLanguagePair to
  // set the new language.
  function languageChangeHandler() {
    var dropdown = document.getElementById('languageDropDown');
    transliterationControl.setLanguagePair(
        google.elements.transliteration.LanguageCode.ENGLISH,
        dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value);
  }

  // SERVER_UNREACHABLE event handler which displays the error message.
  function serverUnreachableHandler(e) {
    document.getElementById("errorDiv").innerHTML =
        "Transliteration Server unreachable";
  }

  // SERVER_UNREACHABLE event handler which clears the error message.
  function serverReachableHandler(e) {
    document.getElementById("errorDiv").innerHTML = "";
  }
  google.setOnLoadCallback(onLoad);
```