# How to switch different text basing on browser language (js)

Tags: javascript, html

```js
var language = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage;
var english = language.indexOf('en') !== -1;
var french = language.indexOf('fr') !== -1;
var german = language.indexOf('de') !== -1;
    
var el = document.getElementById('phrase');
{ if (english || french || german)
  { el.innerHTML = (
    (english && 'english phrase') ||
    (french && 'french phrase') ||
    (german && 'german phrase') ); 
    }
   }
```

```html
<div align="center" id="phrase"></div>
```

Can you guys please fix my code in order to make it work?
As you noticed, I'm trying to switch to a specific phrase basing on navigator's browser language.
But I don't realize where am I wrong with the code...

Comment: Seems to work for me https://jsfiddle.net/webbm/cdoxz06y/

Comment: Are you able to get hold of  div tag -- > "phrase"  ?. Try to put script code in DOM ready kind of event.

Comment: @Danielle Fiorucci use this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32008125/using-javascript-to-change-website-language It works for me!