# html keep language in bilingual site

Tags: html, jquery

I'm working on a bilingual site (spanish/english), I took the advice from the 2nd answer [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32008125/using-javascript-to-change-website-language).

This is the bit of code in the navbar that I use to pick a language:

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="dropdown06" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        <span lang="es">Idioma</span>
        <span lang="en">Language</span>
    </a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown06">
        <a class="dropdown-item coll-navbar language">
            <span lang="es">English</span>
            <span lang="en">Español</span>
        </a>
    </div>
</li>
```

And this is the js code:

```
$('[lang="en"]').hide();
$('.language').click(function() {
  $('[lang="es"]').toggle();
  $('[lang="en"]').toggle();
});
```

This is an example of the code implemented:

```
<div class="title col-12 col-md-8">
    <h2 class="align-center" lang="es"><strong>
            Costura</strong></h2>
    <h2 class="align-center" lang="en"><strong>
            Sewing</strong></h2>
</div>
```

And, it works great, the only problem is that when I choose the 2nd language and I change the html page, it returns to the first one (spanish in this case); how can I keep, when selected, the 2nd language across all the html's?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Why don't you use a query parameter in the URL? http://www.example.com/page?lang=es

You can access the parameters through JavaScript by following this example: https://davidwalsh.name/query-string-javascript

Comment: I should also add that you're tagging this with Node.js, yet your code is jQuery. Are you using Node or just making regular HTML sites you'll just upload to a web server?

Comment: Thanks Tony Drummond, I changed the tag to jQuery - and, I'm making a regular html site that I latter upload to a web server

Comment: This must be a small site if you're just uploading plain HTML pages. Keep in mind you'll have to change every link as well. I suppose you could write a simple jQuery function that adds a click event to all links $("a").click(function(e)....) then do e.preventDefault(), grab the URL and modify via JavaScript, then do window.location.replace(url)... to navigate to page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Method 1:**

You can use [Jquery Cookie](https://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/) to persist the language values.

```
$('[lang="en"]').hide();
$('.language').click(function() {
  $('[lang="es"]').toggle();
  $('[lang="en"]').toggle();

  if ($.cookie('lang') === 'en') {
     $.cookie('lang', 'es', { expires: 7 });
  } else {
     $.cookie('lang', 'en', { expires: 7 });
  }
});
```

Then run the below code block to check for any `lang` values when the page loads:

```
if ($.cookie('lang')) {
    var lang = $.cookie('lang');
    document.documentElement.setAttribute('lang', lang);
} else {
    document.documentElement.setAttribute('lang', 'en');
```

**Method 2:**

Use Local Storage API to resolve the issue:

```
<html>
    <head>
        
    </head>

    <body>
        
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="dropdown06" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                <span lang="es">Idioma</span>
                <span lang="en">Language</span>
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown06">
                <a class="dropdown-item coll-navbar language">
                    <span lang="es">English</span>
                    <span lang="en">Español</span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </li>

        <div class="title col-12 col-md-8">
            <h2 class="align-center" lang="es"><strong>
                    Costura</strong></h2>
            <h2 class="align-center" lang="en"><strong>
                    Sewing</strong></h2>
        </div>



    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        var lang = localStorage.getItem("lang");
        if (lang){
            if (lang == "en"){
                $('[lang="en"]').show();
                $('[lang="es"]').hide();
            }else{
                $('[lang="es"]').show();
                $('[lang="en"]').hide();
            }
        }
        
        
        $('.language').click(function() {
           
            $('[lang="es"]').toggle();
            if (lang === 'en') {
                localStorage.setItem('lang', 'en');
                $('[lang="en"]').show();
                $('[lang="es"]').hide();
            } else {
                localStorage.setItem('lang', 'es');
                $('[lang="es"]').show();
                $('[lang="en"]').hide();
            }
        });
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, I downloaded jquery.cookie.js, added the reference after the jQuery library, modified the first part you wrote, but I just don't get to run the 2nd part when the page loads (I tried in a function in head, after all the js references at the end of body, in separated js file...), can you tell me please how to run it?

Comment: I have edited the answer and added a new method. You can use the second one as well.

Comment: Thanks @Harshana, I use your 2nd method to find the solution I posted.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I arrived at, it's based mostly in @HarshanaSerasinghe 2nd answer:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var lang = localStorage.getItem("lang");
    if (lang) {
        if (lang == "en") {
            $('[lang="en"]').show();
            $('[lang="es"]').hide();
        } else {
            $('[lang="es"]').show();
            $('[lang="en"]').hide();
        }
    } else {
        $('[lang="en"]').hide();
        localStorage.setItem('lang', 'es');
    };
    $('.language').click(function() {
        $('[lang="es"]').toggle();
        $('[lang="en"]').toggle();
        if (lang === 'en') {
            localStorage.setItem('lang', 'es');
        } else {
            localStorage.setItem('lang', 'en');
        }
    });
</script>
```

In case the `.language` wasn't clicked there was no value in `lang`, so, when I loaded the site the two languages showed up, I solved this by adding an else clause hiding one language and setting a value to the `lang` var.
`onclick`, first I toggled both languages, then I modified accordingly the value in `lang`.