# Add another language to my current html page

Tags: html, css

How to use translation in html page content?

I have an html page in English and want to translate the page texts to another language and give user an option to toggle between these two languages, how can I implement this? any approach?

Comment: You may try these JavaScript [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32008125/using-javascript-to-change-website-language),

Answer (score 3):

Try @media
or other bootstrap

try create second (other)page on russian for example.
And do when people press button "RU" redirect to russian page
For example:
RU

Comment: yes thanks but with a second page method i have to write my codes twice on both pages when making changes.

Comment: how can i implement that with @media?