# what is the tag for html comment?

Tags: html

what is the tag to insert a comment in html?

```html
<!--comment--> or <!comment!>
```

Both the above tags are performing the task of a comment(that it is not executed in to the output)but what is the correct tag to insert a comment in html?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to comment/uncomment in HTML code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3757051/how-to-comment-uncomment-in-html-code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Universally, `<!-- comment -->` is being used.

Browser converts `<!comment!>` tag to `<!--comment!-->`, but other than that, i do not know what is so special about `<!comment!>` tag.

You can also use `<comment>` tag for comments.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- Comments Added Here -->
```

You can use the above format to add the comments inside the HTML pages

Comment: I am sorry your answer is not displayed(that i can't see the html tag you have given). I suppose there is a special way to insert html tags into our questions/answers. So can you please edit it ? I do really appreciate your answer @Hari

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- comment -->
```

is the proper syntax. You can check W3Schools documentation for reference
[W3C Comments](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_comments.asp)

Answer (score 0):

The "!" syntax is reserved for declarations such as "<!DOCTYPE..." and not for comments.

see: [What is the correct way to declare an HTML5 Doctype.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10963135/what-is-the-correct-way-to-declare-an-html5-doctype)

Answer (score 0):

You can use like : <!-- Comment -->

Answer (score 0):

Its like this `<!-- comment -->`

Check out [this link for further explanation](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_comment.asp)